# Angular array filter to bring back matching values only

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of clients. Each client has an array of cases. I only want to bring back clients that have the case type of "Open". Other clients will not show in this filtered array. The current way I am filtering only filters the clients with "Open" but the clients that have case type of "Closed" are still visible but their casetypes = 0. I don't want these clients visible at all.

```
 var clientData = {
   "clientId": "1cb8fe0f-2d21-4e5b-99e9-fbbdf0eebdc7",
   "staffId": "b7b0897a-8d40-408e-841b-598c3c425762",
   "clientFirstName": "Antonia",
   "clientMiddleName": "Elliott",
   "clientLastName": "Schmeler",
   "preferredName": "Randall_Jenkins36",
   "clientNumber": "10459431",
   "clientDOB": "1967-04-18T18:59:57.291",
   "streetAddress": "073 Logan Plains",
   "city": "Camarillo",
   "state": "VT",
   "zip": "81652",
   "homePhone": "424-790-1552",
   "mobilePhone": "850-265-2651",
   "email": "Brooks63@yahoo.com",
   "isActive": "Y",
   "createdDate": "08/09/2022 08:50:46",
   "modifiedDate": null,
   "reportStatus": null,
   "clientCases": [
      {
         "caseId": "1045868d-4fca-424d-9221-c287dbd6ecde",
         "clientId": "1cb8fe0f-2d21-4e5b-99e9-fbbdf0eebdc7",
         "caseName": "International Infrastructure Supervisor",
         "caseNumber": "96511392",
         "caseType": "Private referral",
         "caseStatus": "Open",
         "createdDate": "01/01/2022 09:10:00",
         "modifiedDate": null
      },
      {
         "caseId": "2045868d-4fca-424d-9221-c287dbd6ecde",
         "clientId": "1cb8fe0f-2d21-4e5b-99e9-fbbdf0eebdc7",
         "caseName": "Infrastructure Supervisor",
         "caseNumber": "26511392",
         "caseType": "Private referral",
         "caseStatus": "Closed",
         "createdDate": "01/01/2022 09:10:00",
         "modifiedDate": null
      }
   ]
},
{
   "clientId": "1cb8fe0f-2d21-4e5b-99e9-fbbdf0eebdc7",
   "staffId": "b7b0897a-8d40-408e-841b-598c3c425762",
   "clientFirstName": "Antonia",
   "clientMiddleName": "Elliott",
   "clientLastName": "Schmeler",
   "preferredName": "Randall_Jenkins36",
   "clientNumber": "10459431",
   "clientDOB": "1967-04-18T18:59:57.291",
   "streetAddress": "073 Logan Plains",
   "city": "Camarillo",
   "state": "VT",
   "zip": "81652",
   "homePhone": "424-790-1552",
   "mobilePhone": "850-265-2651",
   "email": "Brooks63@yahoo.com",
   "isActive": "Y",
   "createdDate": "08/09/2022 08:50:46",
   "modifiedDate": null,
   "reportStatus": null,
   "clientCases": [
      {
         "caseId": "1045868d-4fca-424d-9221-c287dbd6ecde",
         "clientId": "1cb8fe0f-2d21-4e5b-99e9-fbbdf0eebdc7",
         "caseName": "International Infrastructure Supervisor",
         "caseNumber": "96511392",
         "caseType": "Private referral",
         "caseStatus": "Closed",
         "createdDate": "01/01/2022 09:10:00",
         "modifiedDate": null
      }
   ]
}




Expected Value


{
   "clientId": "1cb8fe0f-2d21-4e5b-99e9-fbbdf0eebdc7",
   "staffId": "b7b0897a-8d40-408e-841b-598c3c425762",
   "clientFirstName": "Antonia",
   "clientMiddleName": "Elliott",
   "clientLastName": "Schmeler",
   "preferredName": "Randall_Jenkins36",
   "clientNumber": "10459431",
   "clientDOB": "1967-04-18T18:59:57.291",
   "streetAddress": "073 Logan Plains",
   "city": "Camarillo",
   "state": "VT",
   "zip": "81652",
   "homePhone": "424-790-1552",
   "mobilePhone": "850-265-2651",
   "email": "Brooks63@yahoo.com",
   "isActive": "Y",
   "createdDate": "08/09/2022 08:50:46",
   "modifiedDate": null,
   "reportStatus": null,
   "clientCases": [
      {
         "caseId": "1045868d-4fca-424d-9221-c287dbd6ecde",
         "clientId": "1cb8fe0f-2d21-4e5b-99e9-fbbdf0eebdc7",
         "caseName": "International Infrastructure Supervisor",
         "caseNumber": "96511392",
         "caseType": "Private referral",
         "caseStatus": "Open",
         "createdDate": "01/01/2022 09:10:00",
         "modifiedDate": null
      }
}
```

This work as far as filtering down the children but if they have closed cases I dont want the clients to show at all in the array.

```
let cloned = _.cloneDeep(this.clientData);
let filtered = cloned.map((i) => {
        i.clientCases = i.clientCases.filter((c) => c.caseStatus == 'Open');
        return i;
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let cloned = _.cloneDeep(this.clientData);
let filtered = cloned.map((i) => {
        i.clientCases = i.clientCases.filter((c) => c.caseStatus == 'Open');
        return i;
      });
let finalfiltered=filtered.filter((el)=>ele. clientCases && ele. clientCases.length>0);
```

During the first filteration,Clients with Open cases are filtered.So client with all closed cases will have empty arrays.

So I have Filtered the "filtered" array so that finalfiltered array will have **atleast** 1 open clientcase

Comment: Ok looks like I was missing that final step. Thanks